how to use class in another module with kotlin in Android Studio
i try to develop app with wear os
i try use 'User', 'data' in test.kt of app at  'WearMainActivity' of wear but it couldnt use..
is it because of diffret package name?
when i add wear os module, i making same pakcage name but its add '.presentation' itself
it can occour some error?
sorry about my poor english
thanks about read it
enter image description here
if i try in same module app (AppMainActivity) its work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

add implementation(project(":app")) in your /wear/build.gradle files dependency block.
But library module shouldn't rely on app module. What you can do is, make another module say core module which will contain the common classes.

i got error AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Unable to make AAPT link command","sources":[{}],"original":"ERROR: AAPT: ","tool":"AAPT"} if i add implementation(project(":app"))
but Just like you said, make another module "libs" and implementation(project(":libs"))  can use well libs class it work well for me
